# disable and reinstall Image onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function show(){
alert("i am pixel");
}

function disableImgClick(){
$(".Dicon").unbind('click');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#turnoff_btn").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    disableImgClick();
});
});
```

i have multiple image which could be clicked , i wanted to disable all they on-click using class name , but i could't make it work , can someone help me on this ? i need to know how to disable them and add them back on.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/y50sd921/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's unbind won't work on `onclick` attributes

I think You can remove attr `onclick`

```
function disableImgClick(){
  $(".Dicon").removeAttr("onclick");
}
```

Comment: thank really appreiacte , one more question but how do i reinstall the on-click back ?

Comment: @darkness: You can try `$(".Dicon").attr("onclick","show()");`